# Setting user permissions for AWS S3 buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My scenario is as follows: I have a single server and multiple clients, which communicate via AWS S3 buckets in the following way:

1. Clients upload files to an ***Upload*** **bucket**, which the server then
   reads.
2. The server uploads files to a ***Download*** **bucket**, and the client, to
   which a file is destined, reads it.

Assume each client is monitoring its folder in the *Download* bucket, so it “knows” when a relevant file is available for downloading.

The access policy I’m trying to apply is as follows:

1. Clients can only write to the ***Upload*** **bucket**.  They cannot list it
   contents or read files from it (not even the ones they uploaded).
2. Clients can only read from the ***Download*** **bucket** (they can also list
   the contents of the bucket).  They cannot modify the *Download*
   bucket’s contents in any way.
3. The server can read and write anything in both buckets.

Since the number of clients is virtually unlimited, I assume they all share the same AWS credentials and there is no client-specific authorization (this is handled elsewhere using tokens and is based on the write-only bucket access).

I’ve tried to apply the above using both user policies and bucket policies, using examples available online, but the clients seem to always have full access to the bucket, so I’m probably missing something major.

Is the above scenario possible, and if so – how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I should warn against sharing credentials amongst multiple clients/users/devices. This makes it very difficult to track what is happening in situations where you are trying to debug problems or protect against attacks.

The better way to grant clients access to the bucket would be:

- Clients **authenticate** to your central application in some way
- The central application [generates Temporary Security Credentials using AWS Security Token Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp.html) and provides them to the client when it authenticates
- The client uses those credentials to access Amazon S3 (they are time-limited, so they will need to request a new set of credentials after a given time period)

This way, you can track all requests that the clients are making and can control access more accurately.

When generating the temporary credentials, you can specify a policy. For your situation, **this policy should be granted to the client**:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowUpload",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::upload-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowListAndDownload",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::download-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::download-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

You would also **grant the Server permission** to use both buckets:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ServerPermissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::download-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::download-bucket/*"
                "arn:aws:s3:::upload-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::upload-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

(You might want to grant other permissions, such as `DeleteObject`.)

You **should not use Bucket Policies**, since you only wish to grant permission to specific entities.

Comment: Thanks @john, this I tested the above in the policy simulator and it works well.  The problem of ignoring the policy that I'm facing is only within the development SDK (.NET AWS Toolkit).

I'm going to follow your leads regarding Temporary Security Credentials (authentication is already implemented as you described).

Answer (score 1):

An interesting approach would be to have a folder for every client. This could be done using the system variable : `aws:userid` . With this with only one policy definition you cover all users and every user has his private area for download and upload.

The policy should look like this for download:

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowUpload",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::upload-bucket/*"
            "Condition": {"StringLike": {"s3:prefix": ["${aws:userid}/*"]}}

        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowListAndDownload",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::download-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::download-bucket/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {"StringLike": {"s3:prefix": ["${aws:userid}/*"]}}
        }
    ]
}
```

the aws:userid is a concatenation of the roleid and the userid . roleid is only known by you , so you need to share it with your customers. userid is specific to the login system you accept.

Comment: since there are many clients, there won't be an AWS user per client.

Comment: This is interesting, the role is internal to the aws account, the userid is not. UserId is the id from Facebook or Google or Amazon login system. See here : 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-user_externalid.html
and here ( search after userid ) : 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html